# Extracting data from response

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I have response like this:

```
<Result xmlns="olineservice" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ResponseStatus>false</ResponseStatus>
<Error>
<ErrorCode>-7</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDescription>data  wasn't  found</ErrorDescription>
</Error>
</Result>
```

and  i want to extract ErrorCode value from response flowfile  anc check if it is equal to  -7 and if it is, I will have to log this.
I tried  this in ExtractText processor:`${flowfile.content}=(.*?)[a-zA-Z0]` 
but it doesn't work for me and trows similar exception:

1. what should i change  to get the value of ErrorCode

[image]

Comment: From triage: you should at least set a very more specific title

Answer (score 3):

Since your input is XML, perhaps you'll find [EvaluateXPath](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateXPath/index.html) or [EvaluateXQuery](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateXQuery/index.html) more useful. For EvaluateXPath, try `//ErrorCode` as the path and it should extract the -7 into an attribute or the content (depending on the setting of the Destination property)

Comment: I have  used  EvaluateXPath  with number(//ErrorCode) and  then used  executescript processor  to get  value of  ErrorCode and then put it into  the flowfile name  but it  is  still Nan  can you reccomend me something  to get  errorCode  number and  write  it i  flowfile as an  attribute?

Comment: In  online  parser  it  works number(//ErrorCode) but  for EvaluateXpath processor  nor //Errorcode  neither number(//ErrorCode)  have  apropriate result